# How do you register precompiled templates in Can.js

Tags: javascript, canjs, client-side-templating

I'm using can.js and trying to precompile and load templates. I've taken my templates and precompiled them using [can-compile](https://github.com/daffl/can-compile)  and then loaded them in the resulting script file like so:

```
(function(window) {
    can.Mustache('block_tpl.mustache', '<template string goes here>');
}(this));
```

I don't think you register it through 'can.Mustache'? Does anyone know how you register pre-compiled templates with can.js?

Edit:

@Daff,
When I use can.Mustache (I'm using can.jquery, btw) I find that (a) can.mustache is undefined, and (b)that if, for example,  I type:

```
can.Mustache('jim_tpl', "<p>My name is Jim</p>");
```

...that when it gets to the Mustache constructor:

```
var Mustache = function(options, helpers) {
            if (this.constructor !== Mustache) {
                var mustache = new Mustache(options);
                return function(data, options) {
                    return mustache.render(data, options);
                };
            }
            if (typeof options === "function") {
                this.template = {fn: options};
                return;
            }
            can.extend(this, options);
            this.template = this.scanner.scan(this.text, this.name);
        };
```

...where it constructs a new Mustache (ln. 3), it passes the template name as the options arg. By the time you pass it to the scanner fn at the bottom 'options' which was the template name string now becomes an object with each property being one letter of that string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're still on CanJS 2.0.7, and we precompile our templates using `can.view.mustache()`

See: https://github.com/reciprocity/ggrc-core/blob/develop/src/ggrc/assets/javascripts/application.js#L1490

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the answer for < 2.1.0 (and I'll mark it as such). One thing though - I've loaded a single script file and it's put the precompiled functions in can.view.cached, but when I reference the name it seems to go looking with ajax for them! Any clue why?

Comment: Make sure you use can.view.toId to turn your path into an underscored value when precompiling the view.  For example:

Comment: can.view.toId("/static/mustache/foo.mustache"); 
>>> "static_mustache_foo_mustache"

Answer (score 0):

That is how you pre-register a view as [the documentation](http://canjs.com/docs/can.mustache.html) states:

> If two arguments are passed, the first argument is the id of the template that will be registered with can.view.

You can use both, `can.mustache` and uppercase `can.Mustache`. Are you running into any issues?

Comment: Hi Daff, I've answered you in the question above... :)

Comment: What version are you using?